# How to store extra properties for IPrincipal-extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am trying to extend `IPrincipal`. What is the best way for storing extra properties?

1. serialize them into cookie and deserialize it on each `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`
2. store them in session
3. make a database request on each `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`

Comment: Could you show some of your code please? I'd asked a similar question a while ago, see if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531287/right-way-to-have-role-based-custom-auth-query-database-on-every-request-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

In my case I went with the first option, as it represented the easiest (and most efficient) way to incorporate the information into the existing authentication workflow.

I think your answer will really depend on the nature of the extra properties you are wanting to store.

1. Storing them in a cookie could be problematic if the information changes frequently AND you have a lengthy cookie expiration period. In this case you may want to implement some logic for expiring a cookie.
2. Using the session would be require you to refresh the properties you are storing when a request comes in following a session timeout - this is likely to occur more frequently than a cookie expiration.
3. A Database request on each `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` could prove inefficient depending on traffic, though doing so would ensure you always had the most recent data.