# Json.NET - convert EmptyOrWhiteSpace string property to null

Tags: c#, .net, json

Is it possible to use a [JsonProperty] attribute to convert any empty string or filled with white spaces to null?

Something like:

```
 public class Request
 {
     [JsonProperty(NullOrWhiteSpaceValueHandling)] 
     public string Description {get;set;}
 }
```

The same way as nulls are skipped when rendered.
When this property is "empty" the value is not set.

Comment: A default `string` is `null`. `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm

Comment: @DavidPine An empty string, or a whitespace string are not the same as a `null` string...

Comment: @RB. I know, I was trying to share how to do it for `null`. Still looking for whitespace handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement a custom `JsonConverter` and assign it to the `TrimmingConverter` property of the `JsonProperty` attribute. There was an example of writing a customer `TrimmingConverter` detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19272300/2410379). Once you have something similar to this implemented you should be able to set both the `NullValueHandling` and `ItemConverterType` properties. This will ensure that the converter will trim the string, and if it's null or empty or whitespace - it will be ignored for serialization.

```
public class Request
{
    [
       JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, 
                    ItemConverterType = typeof(TrimmingConverter))
    ] 
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the official documentation for the [`JsonProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_serialization_jsonproperty.htm).