# CosmosSerializer custom json serialization to trim string values

Tags: c#, json, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to create a custom CosmosSerializer that trims all whitespace from property values during both serialization and deserialization (both reading from and writing to a cosmos container). Essentially I have a container that contains json documents with excess whitespace surrounding certain values and I'd like to ignore the whitespace when reading a document and prevent any whitespace from getting into any values when writing a document moving forward.

I have created a CosmosSerializer and passed it into CosmosClient instantiation :

```
var cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions
{
     ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
     RequestTimeout = new TimeSpan(10),
     Serializer = new CustomCosmosSerializer()
};

private readonly CosmosClient _cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(uri, key, cosmosClientOptions);
```

My CosmosSerializer so far is as follows:

```
public class CustomCosmosSerializer: CosmosSerializer
{
    private readonly Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer _serializer = new();

    public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        //go from stream to object of type T
        //trim all excess whitespace of all string property values along the way
        return _serializer.Deserialize<T>(new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)));
    
    }

    public override Stream ToStream<T>(T input)
    {
        //go from object to stream
        //trim all excess whitespace of all string property values along the way
    
        using var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        using var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);
        _serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, input, input.GetType());

        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringWriter.ToString()));
    }
}
```

However I am unsure of the most performant strategy to apply the needed whitespace trimming during serialization/deserialization. I've tried utilizing reflection to get and analyze property values, but I'm concerned about performance and am curious about a better strategy. Thanks!

Comment: I would create a [Converter like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271470/deserialize-json-with-auto-trimming-strings) and then add that to your Newtonsoft serializer settings.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/trimming) you can use `.Trim`  method to trim string values.

I have used this method in below code to trim string values. It is used for trimming whitespaces during JSON serialization and deserialization for string properties. I used `ReadJson` method in below code which trims the whitespaces during deserialization.

I inserted some sample item consists of **Id**, **Name** and **Dept** and among this **Name** and **Dept** consists of white spaces and these are removed by using `.Trim()` method as shown in the below code.

**Code I tried with:**

```cs
public class TrimmingConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(string);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return ((string)reader.Value)?.Trim();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("id")] 
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TrimmingConverter))]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TrimmingConverter))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dept")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TrimmingConverter))]
    public string Dept { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        string endpointUrl = "****";
        string authorizationKey = "****";
        string databaseId = "newdb";
        string containerId = "thirdCont";

        CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(endpointUrl, authorizationKey);
        Container container = client.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);
 
        var sampdata = "{ ""id"": ""1"", ""name"":"" Balaji "", ""dept"":"" IT "" }";
        var prsn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(sampdata);
 
        await StorePersonData(container, prsn);
        Console.WriteLine("Data has been stored successfully!");
    }

    static async Task StorePersonData(Container container, Person person)
    {
        person.Id = person.Id?.Trim();
        person.Name = person.Name?.Trim();
        person.Dept = person.Dept?.Trim();

        var sampdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.None, new TrimmingConverter());        
        var trimmedPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(sampdata);       
        await container.CreateItemAsync(trimmedPerson, new PartitionKey(trimmedPerson.Id));
    }
}
```

**Output:**
In Console:
`Data has been stored successfully!`

In Azure Cosmos DB Container:

```js
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Balaji",
    "dept": "IT"
}
```

Here the values of **name** and **dept** keys don't have any white spaces.