# Get all attributes that can be applied to classes

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

How can i determine if an attribute can be applied to a class using reflection?

I am currently pulling the collection of attribute types using reflection, basically:

- `GetAssemblies`
- `GetTypes`
- Where base type is type of `Attribute`

then getting the constructors to get each available signature.

I only need the attributes that can be applied to a class, but not sure where to find the usage definition using reflection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get both fields and properties in single call via reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680341/how-to-get-both-fields-and-properties-in-single-call-via-reflection)

Comment: This doesnt have to do with fields and properties.  Im trying to get the attribute usage.. since an attribute can be applied only to a method, or only to a class, or both.

Comment: point taken. i would guess that any attribute can be applied to any class and it would still compile.

Comment: hmm.. you may be right, for some reason i was under the impression that it would not.  let me give it a quick test

Comment: error CS0592 The attribute `SomeMethodAttribute' is not valid on this declaration type. It is valid on `method' declarations only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the [AttributeUsageAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the Attribute class.

You've already gotten all the Attribute types, so you're nearly there. Call [`GetCustomAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getcustomattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on each type. If the attribute type has no usage attribute, I believe it can be used anywhere. If it does have a usage attribute, read the [`ValidOn` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.validon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see if it includes [`AttributeTargets.Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var attributes = attributeType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AttributeUsageAttribute), true);
if(attributes.Length == 0 || (attributes.Length > 0 && ((AttributeUsageAttribute)attributes[0]).ValidOn & AttributeTargets.Class) != 0))
{
   //is class-valid attribute
}
```

Comment: Too many `Attribute`s in this answer. My head is starting to hurt ;)

Comment: @Jeff what, you don't find attributing attributes with AttributeAttribute attributes to be intuitive?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. You need to get the attributes of the attribute.

```
public bool IsClassAttribute(Type attribute)
{
    object[] attributeUsage = attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AttributeUsageAttribute), true);
    if (attributeUsage == null || attributeUsage.Length <= 0) return false;
    AttributeUsageAttribute aua = attributeUsage[0] as AttributeUsageAttribute;
    return aua != null && (aua.ValidOn & AttributeTargets.Class) != 0;
}
```