# C#: How to set an Object's member by passing it a variable name and value

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a class with a lot of properties (all Strings).  I dynamically receive the name (and value) of a property to be set. Don't want to do a 100 if-then's to set the right variable.  Would like to call something like:

```
Person.setVar(string propname,  string propvalue)
```

I have tried the following (based on my limited understanding through various posts here on SO):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MiscTest {
    public class Person {
        public string personName;
        public string personAge;

        public void SetVar(string propName, string propValue) {
            PropertyInfo propInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
            propInfo.SetValue(this, propValue, null); //<--error here
        }
    }
}
```

However, keep running into this error ... something about Object reference not set:

```
Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MiscTest.Person.SetVar(String propName, String propValue) in C:\<long-path>\PropertyTest.cs:line 13
```

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**  I have added the answer to this question -- which was provided by one of the commenters.

Comment: Did you breakpoint in the function, and ensure that `propInfo` was not null? [Type.GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_GetProperty_System_String_) returns null if the property name was not found.

Comment: Also, `personName` and `personAge` are fields, not properties (no get; set;). You would need `FieldInfo`. Try this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12680341/3791245) for ideas.

Comment: @Sean Skelly ... You are correct.  propInfo was coming as null.  I had not understood the difference between fields and properties. I have it working now and will add the update to my code in my original post.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? why not simply `obj.property = something` ? Also notice the difference between fields and properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit:

So after reading OP's answer to my question below, there are several issues here:

**Why the code fails?**

The reason the code fails is because `personName` and `personAge` are public fields and not properties, so you should probably use [FieldInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvalue?view=netcore-3.1).

**What's the difference between a field and a property?**

**A field** is a variable that exists per class instance (per object). It can be modified directly by anyone who has access to that field (depending on the accessibility defined by `public`/`protected`/`private` keywords.

**[A property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)** in C# can be thought of as a "getter" (and "setter" if defined) functions. Usually (but not always) they provide a layer of abstraction to some private field (also called "backing field"), in order to prevent anyone from modifying that field directly. Instead of having a `GetAge()` & `SetAge(int age)` methods, we can write:

```
private int _age
public int Age
{
    get
    {
        return _age;
    }
    set
    {
        _age = value;
    }
}
```

Instead of writing this code we can simply write `public int Age {get; set;}` (also called auto-properties). this allows us to write code like `if(somePerson.Age == 3)` instead of `if(somePerson.GetAge() == 3)`, and `somePerson.Age = 4` instead of `somePerson.SetAge(4)`. It's just a shortcut.

You might ask what's the point of getters and setters and why not simply have a public field and ignore all this non-sense, and the answer is that when you expose a field you have less control over how your class will be used. Let's say that I want a BarMitzvah event to be raised every time someone sets `Person`'s age to 13, With properties I can change `public int age {get; set;}` to:

```
private int _age
public int Age
{
    get
    {
        return _age;
    }
    set
    {
        if(value == 13)
        {
            RaiseBarMitzvahEvent();
        }
        _age = value;
    }
}
```

I can't do the same with a public field (unless I change it to a property)

### What you should REALLY do

I don't know if you have the time or resources to refactor huge 100 fields large classes, but for the future when writing C# code you should:

- Avoid large classes. Classes shouldn't contain 100 fields (private and definitely not public). You should probably break it to several classes, use composition and follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).
- When you want to dynamically set many data points, you probably want to use something like a dictionary rather than many different fields. It's especially true when all your properties are strings and you can simply use `person.SomeDictionaryName[propName] = propValue`.
- Avoid public fields. In almost any case where you use a public field you can use auto-properties (which you should also avoid IMO but that's more subjective)
- When you find yourself using reflection - there's usually a better way to go about what you're doing.

### Original

Why not simply:

```
personInstance.personName = "Some Name";
```

Why do you need all the extra code and reflection non-sense when the fields are already public? Why have a `SetVar` function when you already can set "variables" (actually fields) by simply using the assignment operator (`=`)?

Comment: Because there are almost a 100 fields in the class and the field/value to be set comes from elsewhere for which I have no control.   Wanted to avoid stuff like:  if (fieldname = "xyz")  person.xyz = fieldvalue  ... a 100 times.

Comment: OK I understand your problem. It sounds like it's just bad design, you're trying to introduce some sort of duck-typing to C# which is a static language.  I'll edit my answer to answer more thoroughly because there are several problems here

Comment: I answered your question now with explanations on fields vs properties as well as some extra tips

Answer (score -2):

Based on Sean Kelly's suggestion:  The class members are fields (not properties) and hence I need to get FieldInfo and not GetProperties. So after changing the code to:

```
    public void SetVar(string propName, string propValue){
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = this.GetType().GetField(propName);
        fieldInfo.SetValue(this, propValue);
    }
```

It now Works!

Comment: Great!  Glad it worked.  You can also mark your own answer as accepted, though [per StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=Yes!,to%20answer%20their%20own%20questions.&text=Alternatively%2C%20you%20may%20go%20back,48%20hours%20to%20do%20so.), you need to wait 48 hours to do so, in case someone else comes along and provides an answer you like better.

Comment: Lastly, per the link I posted in the comment to your question, I suggest you have your code handle both fields _and_ properties, so that your `SetVar` method is flexible for the future.  You or someone else may come along and add a property to this class, forgetting that `SetVar` only handles fields.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Will do.